# Is there a way to create variables for react hooks at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Is there a way to create variables for react hooks at runtime, so that the value of variables can be extracted and passed to an API at runtime as against having specific variable names created at design time the way I am currently doing it

See my code below

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react"
import { View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, ImageBackground, ScrollView, Alert } from "react-native"
import { StackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { Button, Text } from "../../components"
import { NavigatorParamList } from "../../navigators"
import { Images } from "../../config"
import { store } from "../../store"
import { RadioButton } from "react-native-paper"
import axios from "axios"
import { SEND_FEEDBACK_URL, showErrorAlert } from "../../utils/constants"
import {
  BOTTOM_HALF,
  CONTINUE,
  CONTINUE_TEXT,
  FOOTER_CONTENT,
  FULL,
  LABEL,
  RED_ACTION_LINK,
  RED_ACTION_STYLES,
  REGULAR_TEXT,
  SMALLL_TEXT,
  SMALLL_TEXT_C,
  SUBJECT,
  textArea,
  textAreaContainer,
} from "./send-feedback-styles"

export const SendFeedbackScreen: FC<StackScreenProps<NavigatorParamList, "Send">> = observer(
  ({ navigation }) => {
    const tempQuestIdArray = []
    let tempStr: string,
      temp0: string,
      temp1: string,
      temp2: string,
      temp3: string,
      temp4: string,
      temp5: string,
      temp6: string,
      temp7: string
    const [freeText, setFreeText] = useState("")

    console.log("<<<<<<BEFORE fetching stored token")
    const token = store.getState().token.tokenValue
    console.log("<<<<<<<PROFILE TOKEN>>>>>>>>>")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(token))
    console.log("<<<<<<<PROFILE TOKEN>>>>>>>>>")
    console.log("<<<<<<BEFORE fetching stored Sales Agent Id")
    const salesAgentId = store.getState().salesAgentId.salesAgentIdValue
    console.log("<<<<<<< SALES Agent id >>>>>>>>>")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(salesAgentId))
    console.log("<<<<<<< SALES Agent id >>>>>>>>>")

    const getSuccessScreen = () => navigation.navigate("Successful")

    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` },
    }

    const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: SEND_FEEDBACK_URL,
    })

    const [checked0, setChecked0] = useState("")
    const [checked1, setChecked1] = useState("")
    const [checked2, setChecked2] = useState("")
    const [checked3, setChecked3] = useState("")
    const [checked4, setChecked4] = useState("")
    const [checked5, setChecked5] = useState("")
    const [checked6, setChecked6] = useState("")
    const [checked7, setChecked7] = useState("")
    const [questIdStore, setQuestIdStore] = useState([])

    // const { setToken } = useTokenStore()
    const barcodeId = store.getState().barcodeId.barcodeIdValue
    const CustomerId = store.getState().customerId.customerIdValue
    const DeviceId = store.getState().deviceId.deviceIdValue
    const questionsArray = store.getState().questionArray.questionArrayValue
    const CustomerName = store.getState().customerName.customerNameValue

    const QUESTIONS = questionsArray
    console.log("questions  >> ", QUESTIONS)
    // console.log("QUESTIONS[0].id  >> ", QUESTIONS[0].id)

    const renderInputRadios = () => {
      const qArray = QUESTIONS
      return (
        <View>
          {qArray.map((i, key) => {
            console.info("key >>> ", key)
            console.info("i.id >>> ", i.id)
            tempQuestIdArray.push(i.id)
            // setQuestIdStore(tempQuestIdArray) --causing re renders
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-eval
            tempStr = eval("checked" + key)
            console.info("tempQuestIdArray >>> ", tempQuestIdArray)

            switch (key) {
              case 0:
                temp0 = tempStr
                console.info("temp0 >>> ", temp0)
                break
              case 1:
                temp1 = tempStr
                console.info("temp1 >>> ", temp1)
                break
              case 2:
                temp2 = tempStr
                console.info("temp2 >>> ", temp2)
                break
              case 3:
                temp3 = tempStr
                console.info("temp3 >>> ", temp3)
                break
              case 4:
                temp4 = tempStr
                console.info("temp4 >>> ", temp4)
                break
              case 5:
                temp5 = tempStr
                console.info("temp5 >>> ", temp5)
                break
              case 6:
                temp6 = tempStr
                console.info("temp6 >>> ", JSON.stringify(temp6))
                break
              case 7:
                temp7 = tempStr
                console.info("temp7 >>> ", JSON.stringify(temp7))
                break
              default:
                console.info("INSIDE DEFAULT")
            }
            return (
              <View key={key}>
                <View style={RED_ACTION_STYLES}>
                  <View>
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT}>{i.questionWord}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={RED_ACTION_LINK}>
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>1</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="0"
                      status={tempStr === "0" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() =>{
                        switch (key) {
                          case 0:
                            setChecked0("0")
                            break
                          case 1:
                            setChecked1("0")
                            break
                          case 2:
                            setChecked2("0")
                            break
                          case 3:
                            setChecked3("0")
                            break
                          case 4:
                            setChecked4("0")
                            break
                          case 5:
                            setChecked5("0")
                            break
                          case 6:
                            setChecked6("0")
                             break
                          case 7:
                            setChecked7("0")
                             break
                          default:
                            console.info("INSIDE DEFAULT")
                        }
                      }
                      
                      }
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>2</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="1"
                      status={tempStr === "1" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() =>{
                        switch (key) {
                          case 0:
                            setChecked0("1")
                            break
                          case 1:
                            setChecked1("1")
                            break
                          case 2:
                            setChecked2("1")
                            break
                          case 3:
                            setChecked3("1")
                            break
                          case 4:
                            setChecked4("1")
                            break
                          case 5:
                            setChecked5("1")
                            break
                          case 6:
                            setChecked6("1")
                             break
                          case 7:
                            setChecked7("1")
                             break
                          default:
                            console.info("INSIDE DEFAULT")
                        }
                      }
                      
                      }
                    />

                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>3</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="2"
                      status={tempStr === "2" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() =>{
                        switch (key) {
                          case 0:
                            setChecked0("2")
                            break
                          case 1:
                            setChecked1("2")
                            break
                          case 2:
                            setChecked2("2")
                            break
                          case 3:
                            setChecked3("2")
                            break
                          case 4:
                            setChecked4("2")
                            break
                          case 5:
                            setChecked5("2")
                            break
                          case 6:
                            setChecked6("2")
                             break
                          case 7:
                            setChecked7("2")
                             break
                          default:
                            console.info("INSIDE DEFAULT")
                        }
                      }
                      
                      }
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>4</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="3"
                      status={tempStr === "3" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() =>{
                        switch (key) {
                          case 0:
                            setChecked0("3")
                            break
                          case 1:
                            setChecked1("3")
                            break
                          case 2:
                            setChecked2("3")
                            break
                          case 3:
                            setChecked3("3")
                            break
                          case 4:
                            setChecked4("3")
                            break
                          case 5:
                            setChecked5("3")
                            break
                          case 6:
                            setChecked6("3")
                             break
                          case 7:
                            setChecked7("3")
                             break
                          default:
                            console.info("INSIDE DEFAULT")
                        }
                      }
                      
                      }
                    />
                    <Text style={SMALLL_TEXT_C}>5</Text>
                    <RadioButton
                      value="4"
                      status={tempStr === "4" ? "checked" : "unchecked"}
                      onPress={() =>{
                        switch (key) {
                          case 0:
                            setChecked0("4")
                            break
                          case 1:
                            setChecked1("4")
                            break
                          case 2:
                            setChecked2("4")
                            break
                          case 3:
                            setChecked3("4")
                            break
                          case 4:
                            setChecked4("4")
                            break
                          case 5:
                            setChecked5("4")
                            break
                          case 6:
                            setChecked6("4")
                             break
                          case 7:
                            setChecked7("4")
                             break
                          default:
                            console.info("INSIDE DEFAULT")
                        }
                      }
                      
                      }
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            )
          })}
          <View style={textAreaContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={textArea}
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              placeholder="Type something"
              placeholderTextColor="grey"
              numberOfLines={5}
              multiline={true}
              value={freeText}
              onChangeText={(freeText) => setFreeText(freeText)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }

    const onSendFeedbacck = async () => {
      if (!checked1) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }
      if (!checked2) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }
      if (!checked3) {
        showErrorAlert("Your Response")
        return
      }

      console.log("<<< inside onSendFeedbacck >>>>>")

      const quest1: string = QUESTIONS[0].id
      const quest2: string = QUESTIONS[1].id
      const quest3: string = QUESTIONS[2].id  
      const quest4: string = QUESTIONS[3].id
      const quest5: string = QUESTIONS[4].id
      const quest6: string = QUESTIONS[5].id
      const quest7: string = QUESTIONS[6].id

      // const salesAgentId = LOCAL_SALES_AGENT_ID

      console.log("quest1 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest1)
      console.log("quest2 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest2)
      console.log("quest3 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest3)
      console.log("quest4 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest4)
      console.log("quest5 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest5)
      console.log("quest6 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest6)
      console.log("quest7 ..>>>>>>>> ", quest7)

      const answer1 = {
        questionId: quest1,
        answer: Number(checked0),
      }

      const answer2 = {
        questionId: quest2,
        answer: Number(checked1),
      }
      const answer3 = {
        questionId: quest3,
        answer: Number(checked2),
      }
      const answer4 = {
        questionId: quest4,
        answer: Number(checked3),
      }
      const answer5 = {
        questionId: quest5,
        answer: Number(checked4),
      }
      const answer6 = {
        questionId: quest6,
        answer: Number(checked5),
      }
      const answer7 = {
        questionId: quest7,
        answer: Number(checked6),
      }

      const AnswerArray = []

      AnswerArray.push(answer1)
      AnswerArray.push(answer2)
      AnswerArray.push(answer3)
      AnswerArray.push(answer4)
      AnswerArray.push(answer5)
      AnswerArray.push(answer6)
      AnswerArray.push(answer7)

      console.log("AnswerArray ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArray)

      const AnswerArrayStr = JSON.stringify(AnswerArray)
      console.log("AnswerArrayStr ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArrayStr)

      const AnswerArrayObj = JSON.parse(AnswerArrayStr)
      console.log("AnswerArrayObj ..>>>>>>>> ", AnswerArrayObj)

      const dataToSend = {
        customerId: CustomerId,
        productDeviceId: DeviceId,
        questions: AnswerArrayObj,
        otherComments: freeText,
        salesAgentId: salesAgentId,
      }

      console.log("dataToSend ..>>>>>>>> ", dataToSend)
      try {
        console.log("<<<<<<<BEFORE RESPONSE FOR SEND FEEDBACK >>>>>>>>>")
        console.log("dataToSend >> ", dataToSend)
        console.log("config >> ", config)

        const res = await api.post("/", dataToSend, config)
        console.log(res)
        console.log("Res >> ", res)
        console.log("<<<<<<<AFTER RESPONSE FOR SEND_FEEDBACK_URL >>>>>>>>>")

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
        if (res.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
          // Get Response
          getSuccessScreen()
        } else {
          console.log("<<<<<<<ERRRRRROR>>>>>>>>>")
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        Alert.alert("Error " + err)
      }
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground source={Images.bg} style={FULL}>
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={BOTTOM_HALF}>
            <SafeAreaView>
              <Text style={SUBJECT}>Device Identified</Text>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>Barcode ID</Text>
                <Text style={REGULAR_TEXT}>{barcodeId}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>Customer </Text>
                <Text style={REGULAR_TEXT}>{CustomerName}</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text style={LABEL}>
                  Please Fill the Form Below to Provide More Information on This Device{" "}
                </Text>
              </View>

              {renderInputRadios()}

              <View style={FOOTER_CONTENT}>
                <Button
                  testID="next-screen-button"
                  style={CONTINUE}
                  textStyle={CONTINUE_TEXT}
                  tx="inside.send_feedback"
                  onPress={onSendFeedbacck}
                />
              </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    )
  },
)
```

You can see from my code above that I am creating an array of temporary radio button values from user inputs but I am unable to get the result of the user actions

You can also see that I am creating temporary variables objects for answer1 to answer7. This limits the component results to just seven

Thats against the requirement

Is there a way around this

Thanks

Comment: How about `const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([false, false, false, false, false, ...])`? :)

Comment: @AKX, we don't know how many objects are in the question Array, but we want to track the values, Care to explain in more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use object in object you can add new key whether to use multiple checked value.

`const [checkBoxStatus, setCheckBoxStatus] = useState({})`

Comment: @Himamshi, Sorry but I don't understand. Care to explain in more detail preferably with a code. Thanks